# How to add NO_ERROR_SCHEMAS in ng2-ionic-rating module

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ng2-ionic-rating plugin but it is giving error when I am building my apk using 
ionic cordova build android --prod

the error is shown below

```
   'rating' is not a known element: 1. If 'rating' is an Angular component, 
    then verify that it is part of this
        module. 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
   '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        <ion-card padding> <h1>Rate this App</h1> [ERROR ->]<rating 
    [(ngModel)]="rate" max="5"
        emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" ")
```

The html code is

```
      <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
       <ion-title>
     Ionic Blank
       </ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
   </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
  <ion-card padding>
    <h1>Rate this App</h1>
     <rating [(ngModel)]="rate" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline"  
      halfStarIconName="star-half"     starIconName="star"  nullable="false"  
     (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)">
   </rating>

   <ion-input [(ngModel)]="reason" placeholder="Please Give your reason">
    </ion-input>
      <button ion-button small round 
      (click)="resolveRec()">Feedback</button>
    </ion-card>

  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Is this module supports typescript and AOT compilation. share the npm URL

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating this is link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `Ionic2RatingModule` to the `imports` array in `app.module.ts`.
If you are getting the same error again the reason is the version of `Ionic2RatingModule` is not supported. Try downgrading the version of `Ionic2RatingModule` to a miner version.

Working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ys4vsc?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: I am not able to downgrade Ionic2RatingModule  @SudarshanaDayananda

Comment: @kriti sharma Why is there any error? its simple. just run in your terminal `npm i ionic2-rating@x.x.x`

Comment: Downgrade to which version?? ......currently m using 1.2.2 ...nd then I have downgraded it to 1.0.0 but still no luck.....@Sudarshana Dayananda

Comment: @kriti sharma I created a working example for you. see my updated answer. compare it with your source code.

Comment: Its not working at all now.....not in browser even .Giving error "rating is not a know element " as I have shown above.@SudarshanDayananda

Comment: @kriti sharma Did you see my example on stackblitz.com. It is working perfectly and if it is not working with your project you have done something wrong. Please create new sample Ionic app and try.

Comment: @kriti sharma Are you using lazi loading ?

Comment: Then try adding `Ionic2RatingModule` into `imports` array of your page's module where <rating> element is using.

Comment: Do you try creating new app??

Comment: Its working now.....thanx a lot... I just add Ionic2RatingModule it in imports array of module.ts file of the page where I am using <rating>